# Debugging PHP in Netbeans: Copy variable name

Tags: php, variables, netbeans, xdebug

I am using XDebugg for debugging PHP in Netbeans.

In section Variables I see all my variables. 
How can i copy name of some variable to clipboard? Or how to copy just a name of object's property?
For example I have variable `$user` and it has property like this:

```
$user->roles[0]->role_title = 'Webmaster';
```

How can I copy property name with its path in `$user` variable so I can type it in my source code? 
(so I will have in my clipboard string `$user->roles[0]->role_title`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sad to say, but I am not aware that this is possible. I would suggest you send the netbeans folks a feature request for that: http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html

Answer (score 0):

Whilst debugging, you can hover over a variable and the contents of that variable will appear. If you click into the contents that just appeared, you can select and copy them. Or just Ctrl-A then Ctrl-C.